# Overflow hidden questionmark split words to two line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show shorter text in fixed width div.

Value is:

```
"http://www.htmlgoodies.com?[value]"
```

I would like to see:

```
"http://www.html..."
```

But I see:

```
"http://www.html...
 [value]"
```

What happens to put question marks to `HTML`

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/85Lt2kv5)

Comment: show. us. your. fiddle. how many times can we tell people to read "how to ask questions" ?

Comment: I put but it is not seen

Comment: Change width:50 to width:150px for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap;` and change the width to display however much you would like. Check [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) out to read more about it.

```
#t {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    display:block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/85Lt2kv5/1/)

Comment: @user448283 No problem, also you don't need `display: block;` as `div` is a block element by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS attribute `white-space: nowrap;` in your css for `#t`